# make a sorted array key

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have this Array:

```
let arr = [ 0.125, 0.42857142857142855, 0.5, 0.5, 0 ];
```

I want to sort that array's order by index like this:

```
[2, 3, 1, 0, 4];
```

Not like this:

```
[0.5, 0.5, 0.42857142857142855, 0.125, 0];
```

I want to get sorted array keys.

Comment: How exactly is `[2, 3, 1, 0, 4]` "sorted"? And what do those values have to do with the contents of the array?

Comment: He is looking for the indexes of the original array in a sorted order

Comment: @Mark ah, right. It would have been helpful for the OP to have included language similar to your comment :)

Comment: Someone with 4K rep should know already how to write a proper question and also know to show what they have tried

Comment: @Pointy Sorry, I am not a native English speaker, so I think I choose wrong word for this question.

Comment: @zynkn your English is a lot better than my Korean :)

Comment: @charlietfl you are right. I did many things for my problems but I thought my working is not helpful for this question, so I didn't attach my trying

Comment: i think the question should be reopended, because the question is now clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can apply `sort()` the [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the array. And then [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) it to keys.

```js
let arr = [ 0.125, 0.42857142857142855, 0.5, 0.5, 0 ];

let res = Object.entries(arr).sort(([,v1],[,v2]) => v2 - v1).map(x => +x[0])
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 3):

A list of index,value can be created from the starting array, so you can sort and remap to the desired output:

```js
let arr = [ 0.125, 0.42857142857142855, 0.5, 0.5, 0 ];
var result = arr.map((el, i) => ({i, el}))
         .sort((a, b) => b.el - a.el).map(({i}) => i);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You can make the code short. `arr.map((el, i) => ({i,el}))
         .sort((a, b) => b.el - a.el).map(({i}) => i);`

Comment: In Chrome this answer is about twice as fast as the accepted answer, and to me is easier to follow.

Comment: In FF `Object.entries(arr).sort((a,b) => b[1]-a[1]).map(a => a[0])` is 66% slower than your solution. Nevertheless, it looks to me more concise.